# Query rows that the datatable field contain any item in the list<string>

Tags: c#, linq

i'm new in LINQ.
I wanna query all rows that the description column string (example value "i am feeling lucky today.") contains/match any item in a `List<string> lst`.
Example the list items contain {"lucky", "bad", "ok" }.
I would like to achieve by using linq only, but I am confuse are below methods correct??
thanks.

**Option 1:**
`var item =`
`from a in datatbl.AsEnumerable()`
`from b in lst`
`where a.Field<string>("description").contains(b)`
`select a;`

**Option 2:**
`var item =`
`from a in datatbl.AsEnumerable()`
`where lst.Any(x=> a.Field<string>("description").Contains(x))`
`select a;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both of your options should work (change contains to Contains).  But if you want to be case-insensitive, you will need to use a ToUpper or something.

For example, this code provides a "test jig" and handles case insensitivity.

```
        DataTable datatbl = new DataTable();
        datatbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("description",typeof(string)));
        // add simple test rows
        datatbl.Rows.Add("I'm feeling lucky today.");
        datatbl.Rows.Add("I'm feeling bad today.");
        datatbl.Rows.Add("I'm feeling good today.");
        // more test rows here...
        List<string> lst = new List<string>(new string[] { "Lucky", "bad", "ok" });

        var item =
            from a in datatbl.AsEnumerable()
            from b in lst
            where a.Field<string>("description").ToUpper().Contains(b.ToUpper())
            select a;

        var item2 =
            from a in datatbl.AsEnumerable()
            where lst.Any(x => a.Field<string>("description").ToUpper().Contains(x.ToUpper()))
            select a;
```

Comment: +1 - I realize how I had misread the question :) In addition to your solutions, you could also use the following where-clause, eliminating the need to perform upper-case conversion of the strings: `where string.Compare(a.Field<string>("description"), b, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0`

Comment: Les, Fredrik, thanks for the reply. it's very useful and this is what i want. ;) i'm going to try on that when i back to my work station.

Answer (score 1):

Found out that if one row value is `I'm not feeling Lucky, bad or ok today.` with Linq below:

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>(new string[] { "Lucky", "bad", "ok" });
var item =  from a in datatbl.AsEnumerable()
            from b in lst
            where a.Field<string>("description").ToUpper().Contains(b.ToUpper())
            select a;
```

the result will return me 3 **duplicated records** of the same row, seem like it's not distinct by default. is this the case of above linq??

To get the **distinct rows**, i need to revise to:

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>(new string[] { "Lucky", "bad", "ok" });
var item =  (from a in datatbl.AsEnumerable()
            from b in lst
            where a.Field<string>("description").ToUpper().Contains(b.ToUpper())
            select a).Distinct();
```