# How to select rows from a DataTable where a Column value is within a List?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, linq, datatable

Say you had a table in SQL and you wanted to find all the rows where a particular column could be one of 3 options. You could write something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE uid IN (123, 456, 789)
```

That's effectively what I want to do with a `DataTable` in VB. I saw this post:
[Query rows that the datatable field contain any item in the list<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123462/query-rows-that-the-datatable-field-contain-any-item-in-the-liststring)

Which seemed to be exactly what I wanted, but it's not working as I expected it to. I basically just used a C# -> VB converter and plugged in my variables and came up with this:

```
Dim item = From a In dtCodes.AsEnumerable() Where
                lstCodes.Any(Function(x) a.Field(Of String)
                ("Code").ToUpper().Contains(x.ToUpper())) Select a
```

`dtCodes` is a DataTable with a column `Codes` in it. `lstCodes` is a `List(Of String)` with some values in it.

`item` just has all of the rows from `dtCodes` though, regardless of whether or not their `Code` column value exists in `lstCodes`.

What am I missing?

edit; Note that I don't *have* to use LINQ, if there's an easier or better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past, I've done this sort of like this:

```
Dim item = From r as DataRow in dtCodes.Rows 
           Where lstCodes.contains(r.Item("Codes")) 
           Select r
```

Does that work?

Answer (score 2):

The code you have looks ok to me. I tried out this test and it (correctly) prints out

```
a2
b1


 Dim dtCodes As New DataTable
        dtCodes.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Code"))

        dtCodes.Rows.Add("a1")
        dtCodes.Rows.Add("a2")
        dtCodes.Rows.Add("b1")
        dtCodes.Rows.Add("b2")

        Dim lstCodes As New List(Of String)
        lstCodes.Add("b1")
        lstCodes.Add("c1")
        lstCodes.Add("a2")

        Dim item = From a In dtCodes.AsEnumerable()
                    Where lstCodes.Any(Function(x) a.Field(Of String)("Code").ToUpper().Contains(x.ToUpper()))
                    Select a

        For Each itm In item
            Debug.WriteLine(itm("Code").ToString)
        Next
```

Comment: The you must be doing something incorrectly. Are you sure your list actually contains the values you expected or contains anything at all?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a lamba expression that should also work.

```
Dim item = dtCodes.Select.Where(Function(x As DataRow) lstCodes.Contains(x.Item("Codes")))
```